# How to "read" a HTML document in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm facing a problem for a quite long time. Unfortunately I was not able to find the solution by my own, so I have to post my question here.

I am writting a little php script that creates a PDF file from a dynamically created HTML file.

Now I want to "parse" the html file and do a action in addiction to which tag is next in HTML.

E.g.

`<div><p>Test</p></div>`

My script should recognize:

First tag is a div: do function for div
Second tag is a p: do function for p

I don't know for what I should search. Regular expressions? HTML parser?

Thanks for a hint!

Comment: try [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Is this something you could use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Comment: @mgraph: Okay, I'll try this. Thanks a lot! Maybe you can give me a little example? I want to do with '<html><div id="content"><h1>Heading<h1><p>Text</p></div>' the following: if #content->h1 available print_h1(); It is an example without deeper sense. Just want to understand the basics because I tried to but don't. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an XML parser. In PHP the `SimpleXML` is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've used several times [phpQuery](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery). That's a nice solution, although it's quite big and seems that is no longer supported (last commit > 10 months).

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is read the `HTML` file into a PHP `variable/object`
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/read-html-files-using-php.aspx

And then use `RegEx` to parse the `HTML Tags` and `Attributes`
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297056/Most-Important-Regular-Expression-for-parsing-HTML

Comment: @simplemotives although it isn't best practice, when doing *hacky* things that OP is after I believe the combo foots the bill. If OP has control over the 2 ends of the system (HTML Creating and PDF Creating) then the actual html file can be written in a standards compliant way, and thus parsed using a good RegEx

Comment: I still disagree.  Even if the OP controls the HTML, he may still have multiple tag variations that complicate regex parsing.  Even if this is a hacky script, there are dom libraries that make this a lot easier.  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/  Include the lib, load the html, use selectors to get the elements you want and avoid the complications.

Comment: agree, but what do you propose? a parser as suggested by @xato? If so, which one, and am I not right in thinking that any third party parser would internally still use some form of expression matching? then again, this is not really my field of expertise! :)