# PHP, write an HTML document?

Tags: php, html

I have right now a .html document that I copy to new directories..

My question is : Is there a way to put text in the .html document between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags?

I'm sorry for this question, I mean with the short explaination, but I have searched everywhere.

Comment: Sure is, open the document, identify the body section, inject your changes, save the file. Where's your question?

Comment: Read the file, parse it with a DOM parser, add the data and then save the result.

Comment: @MikeB how to identify there's my problem ^^

Comment: What kind of proof have you done?

Comment: i think you should start with the basics: http://w3schools.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604793/how-to-read-a-html-document-in-php?rq=1

Comment: It depends of your method: you can open the file and parse it byte by byte while reaching your tag or you can read it in a variable and use str_replace or...

Comment: Parse some HTML file byte by byte o_O. We have DOM for a reason

Comment: @PeeHaa Yup! We have a DOM, but with such a question after having "searched everywhere"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can using PHP `fopen()`  read method , append whatever text you want using `file_put_contents()` , then save file to your server :

source:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp , http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp

Answer (score 1):

On a web server running PHP, `.PHP` files are always processed through the PHP managed handler (decoder, sort of) and that INCLUDES a standard HTML processor. So, you can, without question, combine PHP and HTML in a single file. The key is proper placement of the scripted code and the HTML code.

An example of your "work" would be very useful here.

Comment: I have a .html file with all the html tags, and i copy it to a new folder, and the file in the new folder i want to add "This is Text"

Comment: Do you know WHERE you want "This is Text" to appear on the rendered page (when viewing in the browser)?

Comment: Inside the <body>

Like this <html><head></head><body>This is Text</body></html>

Comment: Then go for it! You won't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not if is an .html document. ...Well, yes, but it requires altering server settings and it's really bad practice.

If you change it to a .php file. Then yes it's possible.

You would have something like this:

```
<body>
<?php 
      echo 'Hello World <br />';

      /*$content is something you would have defined earlier on 
        (it doesn't have to be called '$content' though) */
      echo $content;

?>

</body>
```